# MessageSelector cannot be resolved

Tags: filter, rocketmq

I learn to do rocketMQ "Filter Example", but in eclipse, I don't find MessageSelector. Who can help me?

[rocketMQ Filter Example Documentation](http://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/filter-by-sql92-example/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get, it's at the http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.rocketmq</groupId>
    <artifactId>rocketmq-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```